# Iterating and fetching values from dictionary

Tags: python, hash-map

Here is my dictionary:

```
c_result1 = {"1": {"time": "89.46%"}, "2": {"date": "10.54%"}}
c_result2 = {"1": {"money": "89.46%"}, "2": {"finance": "10.54%"}}
```

I want extract, first key value of `1` i.e. `time`, length of the dictionary may vary.

My code:

```
c_result1 = {"1": {"time": "89.46%"}, "2": {"date": "10.54%"}}
c_result2 = {"1": {"money": "89.46%"}, "2": {"date": "10.54%"}}
flag = 0
result = []
result1 = ''
result2 = ''
for k,v in c_result1.iteritems():
    for k1,v1 in v.iteritems():
        result1 = k1
        result.append(result1)
        print 'result = ', result1
        flag = 1
        if flag == 1:
            break
    if flag == 1:
        break
for k,v in c_result2.iteritems():
    for k1,v1 in v.iteritems():
        result2 = k1
        result.append(result2)
        print 'result = ', result2
        flag = 1
        if flag == 1:
            break
    if flag == 1:
        break
print 'REsult is : , ', result
```

What is the standard way to do this, rather then using flag?

After that I want to extract `time` and `money` from each result and pack them into list like `['time','money']`, but due to `flag` I have used here, I was not able to do this.

Comment: Note that dictionaries are unordered, so taking the first item like this can actually give you any one of the items. Are you trying to get the item with the smallest key?

Comment: @JanneKarila: no I was trying to get first key in dictionary

Comment: But what does that mean? The key that was first inserted into the dictionary? Then you need `collections.OrderedDict` that maintains the order.

Comment: I meant first key in both dictionary, `time` and `money` in mentioned dictionaries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you write

```
    flag = 1
    if flag == 1:
        break
```

The `if` will always be `True`, so this is just

```
    flag = 1
    break
```

You only use `flag` for another `if` that also will always be `True`, so make this

```
    break
break
```

Simplifying this to

```
c_result1 = {"1": {"time": "89.46%"}, "2": {"date": "10.54%"}}
c_result2 = {"1": {"money": "89.46%"}, "2": {"date": "10.54%"}}
result = []
result1 = ''
result2 = ''
for k,v in c_result1.iteritems():
    for k1,v1 in v.iteritems():
        result1 = k1
        result.append(result1)
        print 'result = ', result1
        break
    break
for k,v in c_result2.iteritems():
    for k1,v1 in v.iteritems():
        result2 = k1
        result.append(result2)
        print 'result = ', result2
        break
    break
print 'REsult is : , ', result
```

Removing the inner `print`s gives

```
c_result1 = {"1": {"time": "89.46%"}, "2": {"date": "10.54%"}}
c_result2 = {"1": {"money": "89.46%"}, "2": {"date": "10.54%"}}
result = []
for k,v in c_result1.iteritems():
    for k1,v1 in v.iteritems():
        result.append(k1)
        break
    break
for k,v in c_result2.iteritems():
    for k1,v1 in v.iteritems():
        result.append(k1)
        break
    break
print 'REsult is : , ', result
```

This can be simplified by using `itervalues` and not calling `iteritems` on the inner loop:

```
c_result1 = {"1": {"time": "89.46%"}, "2": {"date": "10.54%"}}
c_result2 = {"1": {"money": "89.46%"}, "2": {"date": "10.54%"}}
result = []
for v in c_result1.itervalues():
    for k in v:
        result.append(k)
        break
    break
for v in c_result2.itervalues():
    for k in v:
        result.append(k)
        break
    break
print 'REsult is : , ', result
```

This is actually just the same as calling `next` twice:

```
help(next)
#>>> Help on built-in function next in module builtins:
#>>>
#>>> next(...)
#>>>     next(iterator[, default])
#>>>     
#>>>     Return the next item from the iterator. If default is given and the iterator
#>>>     is exhausted, it is returned instead of raising StopIteration.
#>>>
```

However this is only simpler if you know it's going to succeed:

```
c_result1 = {"1": {"time": "89.46%"}, "2": {"date": "10.54%"}}
c_result2 = {"1": {"money": "89.46%"}, "2": {"date": "10.54%"}}
result = []

inner = next(c_result1.itervalues())
result.append(next(iter(inner)))

inner = next(c_result1.itervalues())
result.append(next(iter(inner)))

print 'REsult is : , ', result
```

Either way, one should make a function or use a loop to avoid repeating oneself:

```
c_result1 = {"1": {"time": "89.46%"}, "2": {"date": "10.54%"}}
c_result2 = {"1": {"money": "89.46%"}, "2": {"date": "10.54%"}}
result = []

for c_result in (c_result1, c_result2):
    for v in c_result.itervalues():
        for k in v:
            result.append(k)
            break
        break

print 'REsult is : , ', result
```

Comment: thanks again, can you please add explaination in `get_first` ? I did not understand `callback=lambda x: x` and `dict2d`. And yeah I need 15 points to upvote your answer : )

Comment: `dict2d` is just the name, which will be `c_result1` in the first case and `c_result2` in the second. I added a little bit about `lambda x: x`.